# Replace single values according to lagged value in column in R

Tags: r, time-series, apply

I have a ts dataset with many columns. For each column, I want to substitute the values which equal their lag with the same value plus a very small term (any kind of noise), let's say a fraction of the standard deviation.
I wrote the function and used the easy apply function.

```
a <- c(1,2,2,3,4,5,6)
b <- c(4,5,6,7,8,8,9)
data <- data.frame(cbind(a,b))
repetitions <- function(x) {
x[x == lag(x) & !is.na(x) & !is.na(lag(x))] <- x+0.000001
x
}
datanew <- data.frame(apply(data, 2, repetitions ))
```

If I use a single number it works e.g. 1000, while if I put **x+0.000001** it returns wrong numbers.
I know that the solution is not very difficult, but I've found NA issues only, and I'm pretty stucked at this point of the program.

Thank you very much for your help.

EDIT. I hope the mwe is correct, I'm a newbie of this

Comment: Please show a reproducible example

Comment: Yeah, reproducible example would help. Also it looks like `x` in your code is a vector and `x` and `x[x == lag(x) & !is.na(x) & !is.na(lag(x))]` will not be the same length, so it would make sense that this would throw an error.

Comment: @cerpintaxt I think you got the point. My goal would simply to substitute with x (value) + 0.00001*sd(x), where here x is the vector used in the apply function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED

The problem as @cerpintax was saying, is a matter of different length: it is sufficient to condition the replacement in order to get it right.

Thank you very much @jason: your solution worked but I found a bug: when I used your code on the larger dataset, I got some NA instead of the replacement (don't know why).

Here's the working code, very simple! I just hate myself for spending so much time on this tiny bit..

```
repetitions <- function(x) {
x[x == lag(x) & !is.na(x) & !is.na(lag(x))] <- x[x == lag(x) & !is.na(x) &   !is.na(lag(x))] + (0.0001*sd(x, na.rm = T))
x
}
ITA_HD6 <- data.frame(apply(ITA_HD5, 2, repetitions))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `data.table` way that isn't amazingly elegant but it works.

```
a <- c(1,2,2,3,4,5,6)
b <- c(4,5,6,7,8,8,9)
data <- data.table(cbind(a,b))

repetitions <- function(x,dat) {

  dat[eval(as.name(x)) == shift(eval(as.name(x)),type='lag') & !is.na(eval(as.name(x))) & !is.na(shift(eval(as.name(x)),type='lag'))
      ,eval(as.name(x)):=eval(as.name(x))+0.000001]

}

data_2<-copy(data)

for(i in names(data_2)){

  repetitions(i,data_2)
}

data_2
data_2

          a        b
1: 1.000000 4.000000
2: 2.000000 5.000000
3: 2.000001 6.000000
4: 3.000000 7.000000
5: 4.000000 8.000000
6: 5.000000 8.000001
7: 6.000000 9.000000
```

Comment: thank you so much! could you explain me a bit of some functions I've never seen, such as the :=? I have 2 more questions: 1) what if I want to add a portion of the standard deviation instead of 0.00001? 2) on a larger dataset it doesnt add but it rather subtracts

Comment: I got the first point alone, what about the fact that + subtracts and - adds?

Comment: @Giacomo what do you mean by + subtracts? That's not what I'm showing here... Also, in `data.table` you can do things like `x:=.01-sd(x)` within the bracketed form and it will calculate that

Comment: in the example it is right but with real data plus and minus are inverted no idea why I guess it's not your fault..but the NA are really an issue